# Solve this puzzle?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a number, the answer is a power of $2$.

Given $1.000$ the answer is $16384$.

Given $5.000$ the answer is $131072$.

Can someone find a function, so given any number we can get the answer?

Comment: There are many different possible functions. Are you looking for one in particular?

Comment: No, anyone will do

Comment: Well, then let $f \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be defined by $f(1000) = 16384$, $f(5000) = 131072$ and $f(n) = 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{1000,5000\}$.

Comment: Integer, rational, real, or complex power of two.  All positive numbers are real powers of two so that stipulation is pointless unless you mean integer powers of 2.

Comment: $f(1) = 2^{14}.  f(5) = 2^{17}$.  So ... $f(n) =2^{\lfloor 14 + 3n/5 \rfloor}$... I mean... why not?

Comment: The answers of the form $f(n) = 2^{g(n)}$ where $g:N->N$ is a function where $g(1) = 14$ and $g(5)= 17$.  Can pretty much make g(n) anything you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(1) = 16384$, $f(5) = 131072$, $f(x) = 2$ for $x \neq 1,5$. As good an answer is any given how little you've said about what you're looking for.